# Segment intersection fails, not all points are detected using CGAL::AABB_halfedge_graph_segment_primitive<mesh>

Tags: cgal

thI have an strange problem.

I build a mesh (Surface_mesh<Point_3>) using Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.

I want to detect edge intersections between mesh and segment.

I use point_*3, but values comes from point*_2 ( Y value always is zero).

Code works without compilation errors, but I don't get all correct intersections points.

```
ABB_treeEdges treeUVEdges(CGAL::edges(m_mesh).first, CGAL::edges(m_mesh).second, m_mesh);
Segment segment_query(point0,point1);
if (treeUVEdges.do_intersect(segment_query))
{
    std::list<Object_and_primitive_id> intersections;
    treeUVEdges.all_intersections(segment_query, std::back_inserter(intersections));
    for (Object_and_primitive_id intersection : intersections)
    {
    Mesh::edge_index e = intersection.second;
        .....
    }
}
```

This is the result of intersected points, almost fine,  except one. If segment is larger, I get more missed points.

[Points on Mesh.Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjpBf.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a minimal example that we could compile and run?